# How can I get Rhythmbox to stop ignoring a deleted podcast episode?

Tags: rhythmbox

I deleted an episode of a podcast from Rhythmbox because it didn't download correctly, but now Rhythmbox refuses to agree the episode ever existed, even after re-adding the feed.

This may be a bug, but is there a configuration file or something I can edit or delete to make Rhythmbox stop ignoring this one episode?

Comment: You could try loading the feed's URL in your web browser or another podcasting application; it's possible that the episode no longer exists in the feed (i.e. it was deleted by the podcast maintainer)

Comment: @NickWeinberg It's [definitely there](http://www.hellointernet.fm/podcast/64)

Comment: I'd understand if you want to delve into the root cause of this, but if you just want to listen to that episode, the simplest thing to do would be to just download that episode's MP3 and add it to Rhythmbox manually: http://traffic.libsyn.com/hellointernet/64.mp3

Comment: @NickWeinberg I did that, I know how to get the file, I just want to know how to get Rhythmbox to recognise its (and others') existence again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does seem a quirk in Rhythmbox's behaviour.  Deleting the episode actually marks the entry as hidden and it seems you need to edit the database manually to unhide.  Try this;

1. Close Rhythmbox
2. Open ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml in a text editor
3. Find the `<entry>` by searching for the episode title/URL etc.
4. Delete the line `<hidden>1</hidden>` in the entry
5. Change the line `<status>100</status>` in the entry (downloaded) to `<status>103</status>` (not downloaded)
6. Save the file and start Rhythmbox

You can also delete the entire `<entry>...</entry>` block and update the feed and it will reappear.